# rtf layout changed after loading into richtextbox wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, text, richtextbox, rtf

I have an rtf of which the layout displays perfect when I open it in word, but when I try to open it in the richtextbox in my wpf app, the layout is off, and I would love to keep it the same. Is there a way of doing this? A different way of reading the file?

Here is the code I use to load the rtf file

```
openFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
openFile.Filter = "Text files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
openFile.Title = "Select Script";

if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    string originalfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFile.FileName);

    TextRange range;
    FileStream fStream;

    if (openFile.CheckFileExists)
    {
         range = new TextRange(rtfMain.Document.ContentStart, rtfMain.Document.ContentEnd);
         fStream = new FileStream(originalfilename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
         range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
         fStream.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is the xaml

```
 <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="rtfMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="673" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

here is how the orginal looks like

[image]

And this is how it looks in the richtextbox in wpf

[image]

Comment: Adding a picture showing why and how *"layout is off"* could be much more helpful than posting code what simply loads rtf. Do you suspect there is a mistake in the code?

Comment: I was thinking there might be a better way to read the document to have a more accurate display of it in the richtextbox

Comment: just added pictures to illustrate the issue

Comment: Try to save rft and compare with original one (you will have to use some hex-viewer), maybe this will give you a clue what is wrong. If both rtf are the same, then it's a matter of how `RichTextBox` displays rtf. I see there is a margin from left for a first paragraph, which seems to be ignored. Maybe it's because you not using `SelectAll()` before `Load`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 if (openFile.CheckFileExists)
    {
      range = new TextRange(rtfMain.Document.ContentStart, rtfMain.Document.ContentEnd);
      using (var fStream = new StreamReader(originalfilename, Encoding.Default,true))
      {
        range.Text = fStream.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
```

and in xaml:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="rtfMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Width="673" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="250">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
        </RichTextBox>
```

how it looks:
[image]